# Filter spatialite layer with 'not equal' in QGIS

Tags: qgis, filter, expression

I tried to filter my spatialite layer with the

```
"SPECIES" IS NOT NULL OR "SPECIES" != 'Corvus corax'
```

expression, but the result contains the lines where "FAJ" field is 'Corvus corax' (the NULL value withered correctly).

What's wrong with this expression? How can I filter all of the rows where "SPECIES" field is not null or not equal to Corvus corax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
   "SPECIES" IS NOT NULL AND "SPECIES" != 'Corvus corax'
```

AND instead of the OR